# Problema para retornar ao jsp mudando url usando sendRedirect em servlet

Tags: jsp, url, servlet

Faço o login na minha jsp, então mando para o servlet fazer as verificações, e retorno para o jsp, mas ao retornar a url continua com o caminho do servlet, e não com o meu index.jsp, segue parte do codigo que retorno para minha jsp.

```
    try {
        System.out.println("esta no ServletLogin");
        loginUsuario = new UsuarioService().verificaLoginUsuario(emailUsuario);
        if(loginUsuario == true){
            loginSenhaUsuario = new UsuarioService().verificaSenhaUsuario(emailUsuario, senhaUsuario);
             if(loginSenhaUsuario == true){
                 usuario = new UsuarioService().getUsuario(emailUsuario);
                 request.getSession().setAttribute("emailUsuario", emailUsuario);
                 request.getSession().setAttribute("nomeUsuario", usuario.getNome());;
                 System.out.println("anteslogado");
                 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                 System.out.println("logado");

             }else{
                   System.out.println("senha diferente");
             }

        }else{
               System.out.println("nao existe esse usuario");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("não deu pra verificar");
    }

}
```

Comment: O servlet responde o login mas aí não tá dando o redirect, é isso? E não aparece nenhum log no servidor?

Comment: Isso, faz o login tudo certo, o redirect manda para a tela de login, mas a url continua no ServletLogin, não volta para o index, ai acontece que alguns scripts no meu index não carregam, por isso preciso que altere a url

Comment: Vou chutar, tenta usar o foward (request.getRequestDispatcher(<colocaonomedajspaqui>).forward(request, response)).

Comment: o foward mesmo é que não muda url, o sendRedirect que teria que mudar, fiz alguns testes e vi que quando faço o login a url fica no servlet, ai quando atualizo essa pagina do servlet, a url vai para o index, fazendo o que deveria ter feito da primeira vez, sem precisar atualizar a pagina, coloquei alguns sysout na minha pagina, pra ver se não estava entrando em alguma parte do codigo na primeira tentaiva, mas entra tudo certo, sabe o que seria isso?

Comment: Se chegou no servlet é porque ele não tá redirecionando para a página corretamente. Em que diretório está a index.jsp? Também é bom verificar se esse Servlet responde a página index.jsp (está no urlPatterns). Se tiver teria que tratar o retorno para a mesma página.